# MySQL Issue - auto-incrementing field using max value

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with a MySQL database, something has to be messed up somewhere. I have a table with a couple thousand of rows, with an auto-increment key field. However, lately, when I try to create a new row, I get an error: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Even though there are not that many rows, mysql somehow created a row with primary key `2147483647` which I guess is the maximum. The next highest primary key after that one is like `2034`.

If I simply delete that row, the next one will be created with the same key, and the subsequent entries cause the same error.

Any idea what happened or how I can fix it?

Comment: where is your code and/or query where you are trying to insert new row?

Comment: Delete the row and then use `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an `INTEGER` on your primary key column in the database, and the `INTEGER`  2147483647 is the biggest one you can have, so it cant auto increment anymore.

You could switch your id column to `BIGINT`.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ALTER COLUMN yourPrimaryKeyColumn bigint
```